# Los webcasts - ¿seguimos con ellos o no?

Tags: discusión

Vamos ya al sexto webcast comunitario y la hemos pasado muy bien.  Hemos tratado varios temas con un buen grupo de miembros de la comunidad.  Pero, quiero tomar unos minutos para pedirles sus opiniones.

Nuestro [canal de Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg) contiene los videos por si no los han visto.  El problem que he encontrado se encuentra con las vistas de los videos.  Como pueden ver, las vistas no han crecido mucho.  En realidad, los números han decaído. Esto es lo que me impulsa a venir a tratar este tema con ustedes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al comenzar este proyecto, llevaba en mente tener seis webcasts antes de evaluar la efectividad de los videos.  Si los webcasts llegaran a ser útiles, constructivos, divertidos, o importantes para nuestro sitio entonces los continuaría. Si no, les preguntaría si se deberían continuar.

Los webcast toman un buen rato para organizar, preparar, coordinar, y filmar.  Si los webcasts tienen valor para ustedes, necesito saberlo. Necesito que me ayuden a compartir los videos y a opinar, comentar, preguntar, o asistir a los eventos. Sin su participación, es muy difícil saber que es lo que necesitamos corregir or mejorar.

Si los webcasts no les proporcionan valor, podemos dejarlos por un tiempo.  Ustedes deciden.

El [sexto webcast se encuentra aquí](https://plus.google.com/u/1/events/ck7qmabn6devnshjmuqc2l73sac).

**Espero sus comentarios y opiniones.**

Answer (score 3):

[image: Meme Squirtle - Vamo a comentar]

@JuanM, me parece que sería una buena idea seguir con los `webcast`, es la primera versión y la comunidad es nueva, es una gran manera de integrarnos :D

Para colaborar con el aumento de las visitas y el crecimiento de nuestra comunidad, tengo en mente hacer algo así: http://live.asp.net al margen de que vayan directamente a `youtube`, un lugar donde se encuentren todos los `webcast` y con la chance de agregar el siguiente evento al calendario que utilicen; la mejor parte de esa aplicación web es que su código fuente está en `Github` así que podemos implementarlo :D

Además necesitamos una campaña de "Marketing Oficial" por toda la web social: los medios oficiales se lance la señal (el blog de SOes o su `twitter` por ejemplo) y que todos los usuarios comprometidos apoyen a la difusión, estaríamos haciendo eco por lo largo y ancho de la web.

La idea es publicarlo de a pocos en diversos grupos porque hay muchos desarrolladores que andan en X,Y,Z grupos al mismo tiempo y si se publica en todos ellos una vez, el alcance de difusión no es el esperado pues no todos revisan todos los grupos al mismo tiempo, te lo digo por experiencia.

Recién andamos empezando, vamos con todo el power 2.0! Sigamos creciendo :D