# Objetivos del 2017 - Segunda Parte (2)

Tags: discusión

[***(La primera parte de los objetivos para el 2017.)***](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/objetivos-del-2017-primera-parte-1)

Tal y como [les conté anteriormente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/objetivos-del-2017-primera-parte-1), seguimos con la segunda parte de los objetivos para nuestra comunidad para este año.  Sin más demora, les propongo lo siguiente.

Hace casi un año, se publicó en Meta la pregunta [Mentoría y equipos de aprendizaje grupal](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/496/mentoria-y-equipos-de-aprendizaje-grupal) en la cual se propuso la idea de aprender en grupos.  Las siguientes dos ideas salieron directamente de esta pregunta.

### 5. Programas de mentoría

La idea propuesta el año pasado no se va a poder cumplir.  Tenemos dificultades al tratar de abrir las de chat o Hangouts “oficiales” para proveer estos modos de aprendizaje.  Menciono también que el tiempo necesario para organizar y conducir estas clases en-línea hubiera pasado a una categoría de tiempo completo, cosa que no tenemos en disposición ahora.

¡Pero, tenemos una idea que puede funcionar para lo interesados en esto!  Para aprendizaje, lean abajo al #6.  Para lo de la mentoría, esta es la idea: Como saben, tenemos gente que llega al sitio por primera vez y lo que queremos es ayudarles a ser miembros productivos de nuestra comunidad.  Mientras sigamos creciendo, vamos a ver preguntas de baja calidad con más frecuencia dado que los nuevos usuarios necesitan experiencia.  Aquí es donde los mentores nos ayudarán.

Buscaremos a gente que quiera ser mentora de hasta 3 usuarios nuevos (novatos o con cero experiencia con la plataforma de Stack Overflow). El mentor guiará a esto nuevos usuarios y les ayudara a preguntar, contestar, editar y usar el sitio de manera efectiva.  Al terminarse el tiempo, esos nuevos usuarios tendrán la oportunidad de ser mentores básicos para otros usuarios nuevos que entren al sitio.  Así, tendremos a gente lista para ayudar y esto nos ayudará a reducir el estrés asociado con este proceso.

### 6. Programas de aprendizaje

Siguiendo con lo del aprendizaje en grupos les comparto lo siguiente.  Estoy en proceso de formular un modelo de aprendizaje en en cual podamos hasta dar un certificado de participación semi profesional para los que formen parte de los grupos que queremos crear.  No  soy el único que está trabajando en esto.  Es una idea que lleva mucho tiempo sobre la mesa sin que nadie le haga caso pero resulta ser algo que va a resultar en ser muy importante muy pronto.

Tenemos al sitio en inglés interesado en esto también y me parece que si lo empezamos, podemos arrancar con una version beta aquí. Manténganse con los ojos abiertos para más información sobre esto en un futuro.

### 7. Pósters par las escuelas  / centros de aprendizaje

Tengo en mi posesión unos pósters listos para compartir por las escuelas o centros de aprendizaje.  Cuando los vean, se quedarán así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos pósters servirán como piezas de mercadotecnia que ayudarán a correr la voz sobre el sitio.  Antes de mandarles unas, necesito saber el local donde las van a poner.  No hay problema con el envío, lo pago yo siempre y cuando sepa dónde los van a poner.  Pondré la imagen del póster en el [**chat del sitio**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).

### ✔️ 8. Los webcasts

Si no han visto los webcasts todavía, les invito a pasar a nuestro [canal de YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg) donde verán los que hemos hecho hasta la fecha.  Terminamos nuestro primer año con este proyecto y aunque no es una fuente de información ultra-profesional, los webcasts funcionan para conocer a la gente de SOes y para compartir experiencias y conocimientos en una manera informal y relajada.

Continuaremos con eso en el 2017 y esperamos seguir conociendo a más de nuestros amigos en la comunidad.

Bueno, ¿qué tal si lo dejamos hasta aquí? Me parecen suficientes estos objetivos y espero poder contar con ustedes para ver cada una de estas metas realizadas o mejoradas este año.  Como siempre, si existen dudas o preguntas, por favor coméntenlas.

¡Nos vemos por la red!

Comment: ¡Me encanta la idea de los pósters!

Comment: @Juan: Yo puedo poner posters en áreas donde "pululan" estudiantes y profesores de ciencias computacionales en la ciudad donde me encuentro.

Comment: Hay algo que no termina de cerrarme en todo esto.. Ni los profesores ni los estudiantes son los que hacen a un sitio de desarrollo grande. Si no profesionales con experiencia. Entiendo que todo lo que sea para desarrollar el sitio sirva, pero es la clase de gente q se esta buscando? Veo pocas preguntas interesantes o con modelos complejos, y muchas de recien empiezo y ni siquiera se algoritmos...

Comment: @gbianchi Tienes razón al hacer ese comentario sobre los que realmente hacen que el sitio sea de ayuda profesional.  Sin embargo los estudiantes un día se convertirán en profesionales y lo que queremos es el ayudarles en lo que podamos hasta que lleguen a ese lugar.  Nuestro enfoque no son los estudiantes pero nos damos cuenta que pueden ellos beneficiarse de esta comunidad también.  Los recursos mayores seguirán siendo usados para aumentar el number de profesionales y expertos a la comunidad.  La idea de los posters (y otras) es para ampliar nuestro circulo de influencia y nada mas.

Comment: En cuanto al tema de aprendizaje, además de los estudiantes y profesores tradicionales me parece que debería considerarse "a los otros". Me refiero a los adultos con experiencia laboral, que teniendo o no un grado universitario quieren incursionar profesionalmente en ámbitos profesionales que requieren programar con prácticas/estándares profesionales.

Comment: Me sumo a los objetivos. Estoy seguro que se cumplirán por el entusiasmo con el que se transmiten. Creo que se debería recordar a los miembros que visiten la página o hacer un newsletter con las actividades y publicaciones de interés. A veces me olvido y paso meses sin entrar y me pierdo de muchas cosas interesantes. Un saludo y gracias por todo.

Comment: @agujex nótese que la newsletter ya existe: http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @fedorqui gracias! Ya me suscribo!

Comment: Finalizando ya octubre, ¿hay algún análisis de los objetivos aquí establecidos?

Comment: @dwarandae [te comparto esto](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/30/lo-que-ha-sucedido-este-ano/), todavía no hay novedades pero sigue esto siendo de importancia.

Comment: Decepcionante los videos. Estoy dispuesto a estar una hora mirando un *lecture* bien preparado y con material de apoyo, incluso una serie completa de varias horas, pero lo que ofreces son simplemente "pláticas" que no demuestran ningún esfuerzo ni preparación. Salio como salio no más.

Comment: Lo del poster no me parece aconsejable: ya hay suficiente chicos que llegan a pedir que les hagan las tareas.

Answer (score 1):

**Problemas relevantes de StackOVerflow**

Como visitante habitual, mis quejas:

**La búsqueda**

La búsqueda es un desastre. Al final es mejor usar un buscador con la opción "site:es.stackoverflow.com".

No sólo hay una búsqueda; hay a lo menos dos y **no** producen los mismos resultados. Demo: busquen un texto cualquiera y luego empiecen a redactar una pregunta con el mismo título. Comparen los resultado.

¿Necesito repetir lo que todos saben?

**La edición**

Oh, dios que horror! Es inconcebible que el sitio "top" de los programadores los editores sean tan horribles:

- Requieres insertar **marcas** en el texto para formatear.
- No es WYSIWYG. Estamos en el siglo XXI y todavía está separada la edición de la visualización. Tipear, mirar, corregir ... tan de los 70's.
- Un editor distinto para los comentarios, con cero apoyo visual. Si no te acuerdas de los códigos mágicos, estás en problema.
- Las limitaciones del formateo: trata de agregar un trozo de código en medio de una lista con *bullets*.
- Falta una opción para seleccionar y copiar al clipboard el código de la pregunta.
- La ventana de edición es minúscula. Claro que se puede agrandar, pero requiere acción explicita cada vez. También sería conveniente tener a la vista la pregunta, dividiendo la ventana verticalmente.

¿Por qué no tenemos un único editor de texto, moderno y decente, como los de cualquier otro sitio web?

**El chat**

El chat es prehistórico. No tiene threads, para empezar. Sin threads es imposible poder seguir una conversación. Los hilos de comentarios y respuestas deberían estar ordenados.

Eso ya se hacía con las news (NNTP) por allá por 1995 ...

Tal como está, el chat sirve para exactamente **una** conversación. Dos o más conversaciones genera desorden y confusión.

Los chat privados no son solución: yo quiero ver la conversación pública global.

**El uptime**

Es demasiado frecuente encontrar el sitio abajo "por mantención".

**Conclusión**

El sitio tiene el mejor contenido del mundo. Todo lo demás es decepcionante.

Comment: No se si añadir una respuesta en un post de 2017 puede servir de mucho. Creo que tus quejas son perfectamente válidas, pero por un lado aqui no parece que vayan a tener mucha repercusión, y por otro son quejas a nivel global de la red. Te recomendaría en todo caso exponerlas en meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Pikoh. Respondi sólo para ventilar. Si los dueños del sitio no están conscientes de sus problemas, probablemente la solución esté fuera de su alcance.

Comment: @Pikoh. ¿Y por qué aparecen preguntas si no deben ser respondidas?

Comment: No digo que no deba ser respondida, solo te comentaba que la pregunta es de 2017 y que  no creo que tenga mucha visibilidad, pero por supuesto tienes todo el derecho a responder aqui o en cualquier otra publicación :)

Comment: La respuesta es "inoportuna"... llega casi 6 años tarde y aparentemente está fuera de lugar ya que aparentemente se refiere a la situación actual . Debería publicarse como una nueva pregunta. Además, Juan M ya no es empleado de SO... etc., etc.

Comment: @Rubén. Otra falla más de este sitio. ¿Cómo pasan estas cosas?

Comment: Sé más especfíco por favor, de hecho, considera publicar una nueva pregunta.

Comment: @Rubén. Parece que lo correcto sería eliminar la pregunta. En opinión tuya y Pikoh, ni siquiera debería existir.

Comment: @CandidMoe No pongas palabras en otros usarios, ninguno de los dos dijimos tal cosa. Una posible acción a seguir en publicaciones con temporalidad específica como esta, podría ser bloquerlo permanentemente para evitar nuevas preguntas o respuestas. Esto normalmente se hace caso por caso, por ejemplo, cuando una publicación tiene varias respuestas "inoportunas" o interacciones que no ayuda la comunidad. Generalmente sólo las publicaciones descaradamente fuera de tema se eliminan.

Answer (score -4):

Quien mucho abarca poco aprieta.
Arrancada de caballo brioso y parada de burro manso.

Poco sentido tiene ponerse a explorar nuevos territorios cuando la casa está a medio construir. El resultado está siendo dejar las cosas a medias. No empieces lo que no estás dispuesto a acabar.

- No tenemos audits.
- <strike>Nunca tuvimos ni tendremos 3 moderadores en beta.</strike>
- 0 personas se han sumado a [*compartir una serie de publicaciones a nuestro blog*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/722/301)
- Un número tan pequeño de mentores que si hay alguno no lo he visto. Posiblemente 0.
- [Dudas sobre los webcasts del mismo Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/los-webcasts-seguimos-con-ellos-o-no). Normal, tienen una media de 194 visitas. Y la evolución es hacia abajo, 112 en los tres últimos. En una comunidad de 35000.
- 0 vídeos introductorios a SOes.

Comment: La palabra "acabar" es bastante fea, espero que esto nunca acabe... En el webcast que hice junto a Pedro Ávila, yo estaba un poco pasado de nervios, creo que si no lo ve tanta gente es mejor, pero me gustó participar.

Comment: @ArtEze Yo espero lo mismo. Esa frase significa que no empieces algo para dejarlo a medias.

Comment: El tema de los moderadores a mí es el que más urgente me parece. Llevamos demasiado tiempo con apenas uno.

Comment: De todos modos, nótese que esta publicación es la 2.ª parte de los objetivos de 2017. Llevamos menos de medio año y los objetivos de la 1.ª parte están bastante conseguidos.

Comment: La palabra *Normal* es subjetiva (me refiero al punto de las dudas en los webcast), ¿contra qué lo estás comparando pasa determinar que es *normal*? Las dudas en los webcast se han resuelto en directo. Aparte bien dice "*dudas*" y haces referencia a las vistas en cada webcast, no le veo el sentido.